# How to creat a dictionary where the key is the stem and the value is a list of words with that stem?

Tags: python, nlp

In python, I already have a list of words and a list of stem. How to create a dictionary where the key is the stem and the value is a list of words with that stem, like this:

`{‘achiev’: [‘achieved’, ‘achieve’] ‘accident’: [‘accidentally’, ‘accidental’] … }`

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: What would your inputs look like?  There's a similar data structure called a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) that is used frequently.  How would you be using your structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
stems = ['accident', 'achiev']
words = ['achieved', 'accidentally', 'achieve', 'accidental']

results = {}
for stem in stems:
    stem_words = [w for w in words if w.startswith(stem)]
    results[stem] = stem_words

print(results)
```

Prints:

```
{'accident': ['accidentally', 'accidental'], 'achiev': ['achieved', 'achieve']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single line of code using *dict comprehnsion* and *list comprehnsion*:

```
{stem: [w for w in words if w.startswith(stem)] for stem in stems}
```